# How can I emulate a PictureBox control in a console application

Tags: vb.net, console, picturebox, emulation

Is there any way to emulate a picturebox in a console application? I tried this way but the image always returned completely black:

```
    Using P As New PictureBox
        P.Size = New Point(255, 255)
        P.Image = New Bitmap(255, 255) 'I did set a real image, but I didn't for the sake this example
    End Using
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with it?  Your code disposes the control at the end of using.  You should use `New Size(255,255)` for the Size property.

Comment: You say it's "returned completely black" but you don't show where you're returning it to. How do you know the image is black, or is there some code you're using to render it that's not shown?

Comment: The code I posted is an example, naturally you'd return the picturebox before "End Using"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've imported everything needed to show the form, don't use the form.Show method.  Instead, use `Application.Run(New Form1)` to show the form.  This [post](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/317149/How-to-have-a-popup-form-from-a-console-applicatio) has a more complete answer.

You can design the form in the designer,use it as is, or declare it as a new object and change any properties and pass the new object to the `Run` method.

```
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim newform1 As New Form1
        newform1.PictureBox1.Image = New Bitmap("MyImageFile")
        Application.Run(newform1)
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```